# how do i get fetch users with user last name

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api

I have a requirement like, user enters the last name of the person in plain text box, on button click i need to fetch the list of users with that last name using REST API.

How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

```
https://siteurl/sites/KM/_api/web/siteusers?$select=Title&$filter=substringof('lastname', Title)
```

Tested but case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

Here is informative article which provides [how to fetch the user details and profile URL using REST API](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/fetch-user-details-and-profile-picture-from-person-or-group-field-using-rest-api/)